# Secure shared internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-security

I share my internet connection with a neighbor. They connect through wifi. I have computers running Windows and Linux, Android smartphones, Chromecast and TV.

**Question**: how can I prevent my devices from being accessible from other devices I do not own?

For instance, I want the TV to be commanded from our phones, and not from any other device.

Also, our computer file systems should not be accessible by my neighbor's devices. In the same vein, I want to close down any security holes this sharing scheme may present.

Comment: Create a separate intranet for your neighbor, if you want devices which are broadcasting on your network, not be visible from your neighbors devices which are also broadcasting.  This assumes you want those devices to be visible to your other devices, if you don’t want them visible, disable that functionality on the device

Comment: Your not going to be allow your phones but prevent your PC from communicating with a Smart TV that is connected to your intranet and has the functionality that allows your phone to control it.  This is due to how the devices communicate, while I know nothing about the devices on your network, there are actually only a handful of communication standards on the typical devices that you describe.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, I want my devices to see each other. A separate intranet for my neighbor's seems like what I need, how would I setup that?

Comment: @Ramhound I mentioned phones because it's like I use, but in more generic terms, I want to define which specific devices can see which others, be it through MAC address, subnet, intranet, anything like this.

Comment: You can’t broadcast a Chrome device and prevent it from being visible.  What you want is unrealistic. My last comment has a couple typos, general idea, should be clear though

Comment: @AndréWerlang You'll need to configure vLANs and firewall rules on your router.

Comment: @JW0914 I'd set up an address range/subnet for my own devices and then create a rule to reject packets from outside this range inside LAN?

Comment: @AndréWerlang Each vLAN will have their own subnet & at least two, preferably three, vLANs must be created [`vlan1`: personal; `vlan2`: neighbor; `vlan3`: shared _(TV, etc.)_] `vlan1` & `vlan2` will be firewalled from one another, allowing no traffic to pass between the two, whereas `vlan3` will have firewall forwarding rules allowing traffic from `vlan1` & `vlan2` to pass to it and `vlan1` & `vlan2` will have firewall forwarding rules allowing traffic from `vlan3` to pass to each.  You can do this w/ just two vLANs, however its better, for both simplicity & security, to do this w/ three vLANs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My router is quite simple, it doesn't support VLANs. It's something I'll take into account when looking for a new one.

My router supports additional WLAN. On each WLAN there's a flag to "block relay". It means that devices on the same WLAN can't see each other, but can see devices on other WLANs. Not perfect but okay. I placed every device on one of these. If I need to command the Chromecast, I'll use an iPad from another WLAN. Btw in the process I learned how insecure Chromecast can be, specially watching YouTube.

I'll revisit this setup at a later time, if I need to have PC/laptops to see each other. But at least the media devices are invisible.